# MySQL JOIN on different column names

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with similar data but entirely different column names.  I make the query in a PHP page and then use the data in echo statements like this:

```
<?php echo($row['bedrooms']); ?>
```

The current query looks like this:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT mls_number, city, list_price, bedrooms 
                  FROM bonita_property_res 
                  WHERE city = "Bonita" AND list_price >= 1500000 
                  ORDER BY list_price DESC";
```

How do a join a table called naples_property_res that looks like this and still be able to use the php echo as its configured?

```
MLSNumber     City       ListPrice      TotalBeds
--------------------------------------------------
898989   | Bonita    | 200000     |  4
```

Comment: Do you want to simultaneously list records from _both_ of these tables? It isn't clear what the join intent is.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelBerkowski I'm hoping I can do some sort of join and then use the same echo regardless of which table as the data itself is the exact same.

Comment: That's a `UNION` then, not a join.  But this implies that you should rethink your schema if you can.  Two tables with the same data generally means you should combine them into _one_ table with a column identifying which type they belong to.

Comment: I wish I could...I have no control over the tables, I'm allowed to only select data. Its a PITA :-)

Comment: Can you create a user view? If so, you can build the view as a `UNION` query with an extra column which holds a string literal for the source table. That would help, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT mls_number, city, list_price, bedrooms FROM bonita_property_res WHERE ...
UNION 
SELECT MLSNumber AS mls_number, City AS city, ListPrice AS list_price, TotalBeds AS bedrooms FROM naples_property_res WHERE ...
```

The column aliases - something AS something_else - ensure that you don't break any references in PHP, e.g. $row['bedrooms'].

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you want to use a `JOIN`, but rather a `UNION`

```
SELECT fields FROM bonita_property_res WHERE conditions
UNION SELECT fields FROM naples_property_res WHERE conditions
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't tell us what the "entirely different column names" are but it would look something like this:

```
SELECT mls_number, city, list_price, bedrooms 
FROM bonita_property_res 
WHERE city = "Bonita" AND list_price >= 1500000 
ORDER BY list_price DESC
UNION
SELECT entirely, different, column, names
FROM naples_property_res
WHERE ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ALIAS` to the columns.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT colA AS mls_number, colB AS city, colC AS list_price, 
                  colD AS bedrooms FROM naples_property_res WHERE ...";
```

And make a `UNION`.